# Why is WordPress still a tag on stackoverflow as well?

Tags: discussion

To be more clear: Why would I risk posting the question here and have a smaller audience than on StackOverflow.

Allowing WordPress questions on StackOverflow is encouraging divergence between the platforms.

Comment: See https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/why-does-stackoverflow-have-such-an-active-wordpress-tag

Comment: One way to possibly drive the WordPress questions on SO to here would be to loosen up the restrictions on questions on plugins and themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this community closes and votes as off-topic questions about Wordpress-adjacent things such as plugins.

So Stack Overflow is often a better place to get Wordpress questions answered, due to the tight scope that's enforced here.

Answer (score 12):

> Why is WordPress still a tag on stackoverflow as well?

Because SO community considers it in scope at their stack. It’s their stack and their decision how to deal with WP as a topic.

> Why would I risk posting the question here and have a smaller audience than on StackOverflow.

You are not “risking” anything, your WP question is objectively significantly more likely to be answered here and subjectively will get better answers in regards to WP dev practices. See https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4300/847

> Allowing WordPress questions on StackOverflow is encouraging divergence between the platforms.

You are welcome to make your case to *SO* community, but I doubt they will go out of their way to get rid of WP questions there.

Answer (score 11):

StackOverflow has become more of a Wiki these days. I Took a look at the first page, and the questions had a total of less than 10 votes. Users on SO are programmers of different languages gathered in one place. It's kind of overrated.

But here, users here are mostly WordPress experts, not random programmers that might also know how to develop WordPress. There are users on WPSE who are directly involved in WordPress's production.

Your post might have a lower view here, but the answers provided is more accurate, technical, and is by those who are dedicated to develop this CMS.

By the way, the `wordpress` tag existed in StackOverflow before this community was created, so it still remains as a tag and is used by a lot of users.

If you take a look into the [latest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) asked on StackOverflow that have the `wordpress` tag, you will notice that only 3 of them has an answer ( the moment i'm writing this ), and only one of them has an accepted answer, while most of the posts in the homepage of [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) have an answer, and couple of them are accepted too.

### TL;DR

*"Quality, efficiency."*

That's all it's about.

Comment: I'd also argue that gaining rep from answering questions is easier here than StackOverflow as the SO [wordpress] tag is filled with Low Quality questions.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I don't know if i can agree with the reputation thing on WPSE, but i certainly agree with the low quality question. I tried to find a question capable of being answered on SO, and couldn't find any in the first 20 questions.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I could say, that at least about the badges I can't agree. It's not that important, but it's a pity no one here has earned `illuminator` or `legendary` badge. Gaining 200 reputations for 150 times on WPSE is just... not not impossible.

Comment: Even on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) these badges are hard to come by. The 2nd biggest exchange only has that [badge earned once](https://superuser.com/help/badges/45/legendary)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes. Wouldn't you agree that badges and rep points must be balanced according to activity on that particular community? My question on Biology section got 1000 views and 19 upvotes in a one day, while my top viewed question on WPSE has like 100 views in 1 month. SE is such an active community with such a slow development.

Comment: The mods here have no control over how badges work. That is an overall Stack Exchange business idea that they put in place for every Exchange. If badges scaled with site activity or popularity people would gain / lose badges as popularity fluxed which doesn't seem like a fun or productive way to gain / lose a badge. These types of suggestions would gain better  traction at [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes thank you. I know mods don't have control over features. Just wanted to know your personal opinion :)

Answer (score 8):

User input should not be trusted :)

Just because someone tags his question as a "wordpress" question, do not mean that the answer requires actual wordpress knowledge. And since SE have no way that we know of to disable users from using whatever tags they want, the wordpress tag is likely to always be there.

As for divergence.... that is up to SE central, it is not our concern IMHO. That said, people that ask on SO are likely to get a lower quality answer, but again, you can not force people to ask in the right place if they believe that they know where to ask.

On this side the problem is the exact opposite questions being asked and tagged as PHP, CSS and javascript which are basic level questions better asked on SO.